# Label-disjoint paths in directed graphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, disjoint-paths

Checking if there are two *edge-disjoint* paths from $s$ to $t$ 
in a given undirected graph $G$ is in P via a standard solution based on maxflow. 
I am interested in the complexity of the following *edge-labeled version* and
whether it is in P or not.

**Input**: An edge-labeled graph $G$ and two vertices $s$ and $t$ satisfying the following condition:

> every label in $G$ occurs exactly twice.

**Output**: are there two label-disjoint paths in $G$ from $s$ to $t$?

Two paths are *label disjoint* iff
the labels appearing in the respective paths are disjoint.

**Example**: 
suppose $G$ is given by $(s, a, v1)$, $(v1, b, t)$, $(s, b, v2)$, $(s, c, v2)$, $(v2, a, t)$, $(v2, c, t)$. Then $s-a-v1-b-t$ and $s-c-v2-c-t$ are two label-disjoint simple paths from $s$ to $t$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem becomes NP-complete ... this is a "graphical" :-) reduction from 3-SAT ... it should be self-explanatory (... if not let me know).

[image]

Two notes:

- +X1a, -X1a, +X1b, -X1b,...,+X2a,-X2a, ...,dum1,...,dum4 are all *distinct* labels;
- in the figure  each label appears $\leq 2$ times; but it is *straightforward* to make each label appears *exactly 2 times* adding some dum nodes+edges+labels to pair them up.